# Facebook Send button causing horizontal scroll

Tags: css, facebook, button, send, horizontal-scrolling

I'm working on Ruby On Rails, and just integrated Facebook Send button in a project. When Clicked on the "Send" button, the popup window is going out of the screen and causing horizontal scrollbar. I tried a few solutions on some blog-sites and stackoverflow, but could not resolve the issue.

Here are some screen shots:

1. before clicking Send button https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiS7m.jpg
2. after clicking Send button https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x4Su.jpg

The code in View:

fbsend.html.erb (using HTML5 code)

```
<div class="right">
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-send" data-href="MY_SITE_URL"></div>
</div>
```

application.html.erb

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=MY_APP_ID&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script>
        FB.init({
            appId: "MY_APP_ID",
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
</script>
```

How can I fix the issue, so the popup will fit in screen and won't cause horizontal scrollbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the comment box is placed into its own iframe, so you should be able to re-position it in your own CSS independently from the button/etc.

One issue with that approach is that the small comment "pointer" triangle on the top of the comment box will no longer aim at the triggering button. Maybe an `overflow:hidden` on a parent container could allow you to hide that part from view.

Good luck!

Comment: I need to apply `left:-343px;` to `span.fb_send_button_form_widget` and `.left: 365px;` to `.nub` to show the widget as expected. But when I mentioned these properties in CSS it won't apply to it. +1 for the suggestion. But it has not solved the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I only tried it on the facebook button demo page, but it seemed to work. Does the nub class apply to content within the iframe? If so, then it will not have any impact since you cannot alter the content of the iframe, but rather you need to apply the styles to the iframe element itself.

Comment: I just saw that you're referring to the small pointer in terms of the nub class. In order to hide that, you'll likely need to use some CSS trickery, likely with a wrapping container around the iframe that cuts off the top and has it's own border to compensate. Feels a bit hackish, but that's iframes for ya!

Comment: I think the iframe is created on the fly by FB javascript and that is why the CSS is not getting applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display:none` to `#fb-root` worked for me:

```
<div id="fb-root" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, in the picture it appears the send box, upon click, is extending the width of the window with a scroll bar so you can scroll to the box. That's normal. Your choices:

a. Move the send button further left so upon click, it doesn't go past the window border, so no need for scroll bars.

b. Add a `overflow-x:hidden;` styling property to your `<body>` element's css. This way, users just won't be able to see the whole box.