# Twitter "Follow" button causing horizontal scroll bar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

My one-page application is working well with Bootstrap on a multitude of devices, however although the Twitter "follow" button is responsive it adds a horizontal scrollbar to the page - which affects the use of my image carousel.

I have the viewport `meta` in place:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;">`

and this is the markup causing the problem:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/crmpicco" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true"
           data-size="large">Follow @crmpicco</a>
        <script>!function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
                if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }
            }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both `row` and `col-lg-12` classes are standard from Twitter Bootstrap. But it is this code only that is introducing a horizontal scroll bar in Safari on the iPhone.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/7551752/707636. Hope it'll help...

Comment: @Bongs Thanks, the `overflow: hidden;` on that link certainly helped. Between that and changing the Twitter follow button settings to use `data-size="medium"` it's working great now. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button

Comment: Cool, you can post the fixes in your code as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by tweaking the CSS of the container to:

```
.twitter_container {
    padding-top    : 1.5em;
    padding-bottom : 1.5em;
    text-align     : center;
    margin         : 0 auto;
}
```

And changing the size of the Twitter button using the `data` attribute:

```
<div class="twitter_container">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/crmpicco" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true"
       data-size="medium">Follow @crmpicco</a>
    <script>!function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
```

You can see the result [here](http://www.wrestlemaniamainevent.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably because you have your parent as a `row` class.

`row` only has one major style, and that is to have a -15px margin on both the left and right, like so:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Simply remove the parent div with the class of `row` and you should be fine:

Updated code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/crmpicco" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" data-size="large">Follow @crmpicco</a>
    <script>!function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
```

[**EXAMPLE WITH `ROW`**](http://www.bootply.com/9P1rarNhM7)

[**EXAMPLE WITHOUT `ROW`**](http://www.bootply.com/pJ6jan4gTC)

Comment: Those links appear to be dead.

Comment: That didn't appear to work for me when testing on iOS (iPhone 5). I managed to get it working anyway (see my comment above). Thanks for the comment.